# Редакторе EditPlus - переключение между вкладками

Tags: редактор

Как в редакторе EditPlus задать "карусельное" переключение между двумя вкладками привычным сочетанием Ctrl+Tab, а не Ctrl+Shift+Tab?

Answer (score 0):

В настройках удалось задать сочетание в разделе Window - Last visited window. В нём нужно задать сочетание Ctrl+Tab и две последние вкладки начали переключаться между собой. Жуть как удобно!